# TSQL granting read and write permissions to all tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is setting

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'User'
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datawriter', N'User'
```

Is the same as granting SELECT/INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE on all tables to User

```
GRANT SELECT ON  [Schema].[Table] TO [User]
GRANT INSERT ON  [Schema].[Table] TO [User]
GRANT DELETE ON  [Schema].[Table] TO [User]
GRANT UPDATE ON  [Schema].[Table] TO [User]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From MSDN ([db_datawriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175039.aspx), [db_datareader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188629.aspx)) :

> Members of the db_datawriter fixed database role can add, delete, or change data in all user tables.
>
> Members of the db_datareader fixed database role can run a SELECT statement against any table or view in the database.

So, the effect is the same, only easier to administer in the first case.